# All users applications on taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows

I would like to know, is it possible to see all logged user's active applications on task bar at Windows 7? I mean like user X has firefox and chrome ran and user Y got paint ran i switch to user X and is there a way to see paint on user X taskbar?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not possible without 3rd party applications. There is, however, an alternative available by default within Windows.

If you rightclick on your taskbar and go to the Task Manager you can click on the `Users` tab and it lists all the programs running on each logged in user. Bear in mind you may need to be an administrator to view this information.

I have taken a screenshot from my test server. My server is Windows 8.1 so the layout is a little different but the tab is available in the same location for Windows 7.

[image: Screenshot of the task manager users tab in Windows 8.1]